# Переход с русской версии сайта на английскую версию

Tags: javascript, html, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать переход между языковыми версиями (напр. я нахожусь в разделе Новости на русском языке, автоматический переход в этот же раздел, при нажатии на английскую языковую версию сайта)

Comment: побольше деталей пожалуйста, как генерируется переведенный текст на странице, на стороне сервера или клиент получает бандл с набором ключ-значение?

Comment: На хостинге хранятся, можно сказать 2 сайта, русская версия и когда выбираем англ. язык переходим на такой же сайт, только англ. версии. В адресной строке подставляется /en/...

Comment: Самый простой способ использовать плагин google. Он вставляется в сайт и можно на любой почти язык мира переводить сайт.

Answer (score 0):

Этот вопрос уже поднимался, ищите ответ внимательнее, прежде чем писать вопрос.
Вот ссылки : [тык](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/512917/%D0%9C%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-cookies), [тык](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/424134/%D0%9C%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5).

**UPD.**
Есть несколько способов решения вашей проблемы:

**Способ 1.** “Картина ананас, я на кукушке”. Автоматический перевод
Когда работы по переводу много, делать ее не хочется, и требований особых нет, сгодится автоматический переводчик Google.Формально все хорошо.Качество среднее, трудоемкость крайне низкая, новые языки добавлять не надо — Google знает все.

**Способ 2.** “Наивный программист”. Поля и папки.
Наивный программист, впервые столкнувшийся с задачей создания языковой версии, считает что различаться будут только тексты и картинки. Код, структуру, дизайн, интерфейс он переводить не планирует.
Поэтому в базе данных появляются поля для текстов на других языках.
Теоретически все нормально. На практике:

Если английского контента нет, придется показывать русский. Для этого проверять существование файлов и так далее. Нужно редактировать код.

1. Нужно будет сделать пакет флагов видимости новости в каждой языковой
   версии. И написать код для проверки. Везде.
2. “Хлебные крошки” часто берутся из свойств разделов, таблиц,
   каталогов и сами не заработают. Писать код.
3. Добавление французской версии требует повторения всей процедуры и
   еще одного усложнения кода.
   Судя по всему, на этой схеме основана работа сайтов РУСАЛа и Правительства РФ.
   Способ 3. Спецальные плагины: [тык](http://web-profi.by/3-plagina-dlya-perevoda-vashego-sajta-na-drugie-yazyki/)

Comment: Не понял как с этим работать! Можно подробнее.

Comment: Поищи в google на php есть реализация данной функции, которая переключает или по кнопке или по геолокации клиента, она в открытом доступе есть. Только там насколько помню идет реализация в отдельный файл, но если голова на месте, то можно организовать и через БД.